# In Vue js -> v-model how I inegrate vlaue?

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

```
<table class="table table-sm m-table table-bordered borderless">
       <thead class="thead-inverse" >
          <tr>
            <th>Sl</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Oepning Stock </th>
            <th>Current Stock</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr v-for="(details, index) in product_lists">
           <td scope="row">
             {{ index +1 }}
           </td>
           <td>
              {{details.product_name}}
           </td>
           <td>
              <span v-model="details.inventory_stocks_open_qty"></span>
          </td>
          <td>
                <input type="hidden" v-model="details.inventory_current_stocks_product_id" :value='details.id'   >
                <input type="number" v-model="details.inventory_stocks_current_qty" class="form-control form-control-sm m-input" placeholder="">
          </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

---

- How can we put v-bind or :value in a hidden filled by vue js
- I can not put the Product id value in  :value='details.id'

Comment: please include your vuejs script in the question

Comment: using v-model is also defining the value, you don't have to use :value if you already use v-model (except for checkbox and radio button)

Comment: I know that v-model defines the  value, but if I want dine value other wise what should I do ? Thanks  :)

Comment: v-model="details.id"  is enough to bind the value to the text box. Nothing else is needed. Why are using hidden text anyways? It is already stored in the model.

Comment: I have a input field : inventory_current_stocks_product_id
I want  to product table  id  here.

Main db table stock -> inventory_current_stocks_product_id
Product id

Onload  I want bind the value. 
Thanks

Comment: First I suggest to add a `key` to your `v-for`, explanation [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key). As @ChristhoferNatalius mentioned, `v-model` already bind "value" so you should use another variable, see [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)